# Fish shell vi-mode is missing "repeat" command (dot/period/. key in Zsh)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fish, vi-mode

I recently moved from Zsh to Fish, and I'm having a problem with vi-mode in Fish.  There doesn't seem to be a "repeat" keybinding, like in Zsh's vi-mode (bound to the "dot" `.`).  I think this is one of the most useful commands in vi-mode since it can prevent you from repeating commands.

Is there a way to add this command to vi-mode in the Fish shell. Any idea how am I supposed to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the Unix & Linux Stack.  I'm assuming you mean the Zsh `vi-repeat-change` keybinding, which is bound to `.` by default?  Could you provide some examples of how you used it?  Be as specific as possible - Provide an example command-line, the change you made (with keystrokes) and then how you used `.` to repeat that change?  We might be able to come up with some alternatives for that workflow in Fish.  Thanks!

Comment: the "dot command" that i mentioned is actually a native built-in command in vi or vim, but in this case, when I am in vi mode, I am not able to use that command, but back when I used it in zsh it worked. 

The use case that could happened for this command:
 - after dd or dw commnad, the dot command will delete another line/word

Comment: I'm familiar with the "repeat" `.` command, and that's the `vi-repeat-change` binding in Zsh.  Been using it for (literally) decades in vi itself.  But I'm struggling to think when I'd use it on the command-line in a shell.  `dd` doesn't seem to apply, since there's *only* one line in the shell (so what would you be repeating?).  And I've never had the need to edit a command-line where I've done a `dw` and then needed to repeat the operation in a separate location.  And that would just be a one-character savings in typing anyway.

Comment: So again, what's your use-case where this because "one of the most useful commands" for editing at the command-line in the Fish shell?  We may be able to help you come up with an alternative.  *Note: If you @tag people when replying, they will be notified that you responded.*

Comment: And in case it helps, remember you can always move the command-line to "real" `vim` with *Alt+e* or *Alt+V*, assuming that `VISUAL=vim`.

Comment: I just realized, when looking at the PowerShell readline docs on an unrelated topic, that your `dd` example might come from a multi-line edit, and I just wasn't thinking in enough dimensions.  Is that the case?  Are you usually using the `.` (repeat) command when in multi-line editing in the shell?  In that case, the *Alt+E*/*Alt+V* to edit the current command-line in `vim` may just be your best approach.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds One thing I frequently run into is wanting to repeat a command like `dtd` where I'm trying to clear some segment of a previous line. There is no `dtd..` and no `d3td`, no search with `/`, so the easiest way is often `dtddtddtd`

Answer (score 3):

It appears the `vi-redo` command is not implemented (yet?). There's an open issue here: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/8319